# Late 70s/early 80s space movie featuring a spaceship shaped like a hand

Tags: story-identification, movie

This is a movie I remember watching as a kid—it might be one of the first movies I saw in a theater by myself, during the summer, probably using one of those summer passes.  So I'm placing it late 70s early 80s.  Other movies I may have seen around that time might have been [Candle Shoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candleshoe)—but that might not be accurate.

The key visual I remember is one of the space ships was shaped like a hand.  And the hand changed shape when it went into battle.

When a group of space ships traveled together, they moved like roller coaster cars all inline and on a track.

**Edit**: I assume this was an American film as its not likely I saw a foreign film as kid in a USA small southern town, none the less.

Comment: While it seems likely that @mwarren answer is correct, more details (where you saw the movie and in what language, for instance) would make this a better question.

Comment: Added some location details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This could be [Starcrash (1978)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079946/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), it's an Italian film and does include a hand shaped space ship. A picture of the hand shaped ship is at [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079946/mediaviewer/rm269039360?ref_=ttmi_mi_all_sf_19).

Comment: Some of the space scenes do look familiar.  And I scrolled some of the other pictures...the shot where the younger guy is 'holding' green energy in his hand convinced me.  I'm pretty sure that was the movie.  thank you.

Comment: That hand-shaped ship looks like it was made out of LEGO.